# Next.js, potfolio starter kit, posts

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

I try to use https://vercel.com/templates/next.js/portfolio-starter-kit
but I can't refresh preview the page in "Posts". It stays the same even if I change .md

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bzJwH.png)

How to update message previews and display them in "Posts"?

I try to change .md files in /pages/posts
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AX1VR.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.